# output logical series based on multiple conditions pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to create a new series of logical values based on the evaluation of multiple conditions.

For example

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[40, 20, 50, 5, 80], 'value': ['a', 'd', 'g', 'g', 'g']})
​
> df[(df.id > 40) & (df.value.isin(['a', 'g']))]

id  value
2   50  g
4   80  g
```

However I would like to return a logical series i.e.

```
False 
False 
True 
False 
True
```

I'd like to do with with pandas methods if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
s = (df.id > 40) & (df.value.isin(['a', 'g']))
print(s)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need ?

```
(df.id > 40) & (df.value.isin(['a', 'g']))
Out[2059]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```